# Angular array interpolation error

Tags: arrays, angularjs, interpolation

I have an array of offers and want to show the first and last offer. In template I have like this:

```
<h1>
We fount [[ctrl.getLengthSavings()]] offers, lowest
being [[ctrl.getSmallest()|number:0]] eur 
and  highest is [[ctrl.getBiggest()|number:0]] eur.
</h1>
```

In controler I have:

```
this.getBiggest = function () {
        return _this.controller.offer[0].price;
    };

this.getSmallest = function () {
        var lastIndex = _this.controller.offer.length - 1;
        return _this.controller.offer[lastIndex].price;
    };
```

I get the results fine, but I also get an interpolation error:

```
Error: error:interr. Interpolation Error <br />
Can't interpolate...  "Cannot read property 'length' of null" && "Cannot read property '0' of null"
```

Comment: Are you sure that `_this.controller.offer` is a non-empty array? It seems to be `null` here.

Comment: it's not empty. I get correct results on page, but also I get that interpolate error

Comment: How do you get this variable? By an asynchronous request?